# How to change datagrid cell fore colors as dynamically using c#

Tags: c#-4.0, datagridview, windows

I know this is a stupid question but i can't get my desired out put.Actually i want change the datagridview cell fore colors as dynamically for this i have logic like this

```
 this.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

but this is  not apply to the cell(even cell background also not applied),

But i  get the fore color name what i assigned to the cell

```
   string colorname = this.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Style.ForeColor.Name;
```

.Is there any mistake in my query please help me.

Comment: Why `this.dataGridView1` in first line and `objPreview.dataGridView1` in second line? Is it a problem?

Comment: just i am creating object to the gridview that why i am using objPreview.dataGridView1.Now,i change that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
dataGridView1[col, row].Style.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
```

I hope This help!

Answer (score 0):

To customize the styles of cells with particular values, implement a handler for the DataGridView.CellFormatting event. Handlers for this event receive an argument of the DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs type. This object contains properties that let you determine the value of the cell being formatted along with its location in the DataGridView control. This object also contains a CellStyle property that is initialized to the value of the InheritedStyle property of the cell being formatted. You can modify the cell style properties to specify style information appropriate to the cell value and location.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yef90x0.aspx)

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex == 0)
        e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

The result is provided below:

[image]

Insert preferred indices instead of zeros in if statement to change ForeColor of only those cells that you need.

Comment: Hi thank you for giving response, i have check a link that is given by and i try the code, it is working but it apply all cells not a single cell.

Comment: yah i get one color if i set indices as 0,0 but when i need to set color at Row[0].cell[1] in this time it assign all the cells of second column not one cell.